# Unable to upload a file using HttpsUrlConnection on AWS bucket

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl, httpsurlconnection

I got a `403` response code when I tried to upload a file using `HttpsUrlConnection` on the AWS bucket.

Please see my code:

```
    String fileToUpload = "/data/data/YTI.tar.xz";
    String uploadUrl = "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/";
    Log.v(TAG, " fileToUpload: " + fileToUpload);
    Log.v(TAG, " uploadUrl: " + uploadUrl);

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(fileToUpload);
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);

        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory());
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        connection.setRequestProperty("x-amz-acl", "bucket-owner-full-control");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", " ");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode((int) file.length());

        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            Log.v(TAG, " bytesRead: ");
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        outputStream.flush();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.v(TAG, "getResponseMessage: " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.v(TAG, "File uploaded successfully!");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "File upload failed with response code: " + responseCode);
            PrevaLog.e(ErrorCode.E_DIGI_UPLOAD_FAILED, "Upload failure of the DIGI report.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        PrevaLog.e(ErrorCode.E_DIGI_UPLOAD_FAILED, "Upload failure of the DIGI report.");
    }
```

However, when I tried it using curl it uploads successfully with 200 status code.
Here is my `curl` command:

```
curl -v --cacert /system/vendor/certs/trusted/cacert.pem -H "x-amz-acl: bucket-owner-full-control" --request PUT --upload-file YTI.tar.xz "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.